# rewrite rules from apache to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I've got a problem converting a rewrite rule from Apache to nginx. In Apache I used a `.htaccess` file containing this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>        
RewriteEngine On        
RewriteRule ^(.*)-single.*php$ single.php?id=$1 [L]    
</IfModule>
```

to rewrite URL for a gallery (displaying a single image). This `.htaccess` file is located in the specific folders but the tree can be like this:

> /galleries/album1
>
> /galleries/set1/album2
>
> /galleries/set2/set3/album3

And the Folder name "Album" can vary (europe, horses, whatever)

The rule itself I would rewrite like this

```
rewrite ^/(.*)-single.*php$ /single.php?id=$1 break;
```

but how can I apply this rule only if for the specific folders? Thought about looking for a specific file as a condition (which only exists in the folders I would like to apply the rule) but I can't figure it out.
Please help!

**Edit:**
Trying to start with a simple example: 
If someone is browsing a gallery he can use a link which opens the image. This link can look like this (autogenerated)

> ...rvserver.net/galleries/album-set/album-2/DSC01154-single.php

This link for social media use but it only works when it Looks like this

> ...rvserver.net/galleries/album-set/album-2/single.php?id=DSC01154

so you see the only thing changed is the last part of the URL. The front part (until .../galleries/) is always the same and the last part (XXX-single.php) too. Maybe this helps